# How to convert this string 20346017621 in to 20-34601762-1

Tags: node.js

How we can set up a function on node

After first two number and last number, we want to add - hyphen

able to get a string
like this:xxzzzzzzzzx

and convert in to this:xx-zzzzzzzz-x

```
example of what we need   
function tranformer (xxzzzzzzzzx){
NOT SURE HOW TO SOLVE THIS
return xx-zzzzzzzz-x
}
```

Thanks we really will appreciate this!

Not idea how to mange this task.

Comment: after first two number and last number, you want to add `-` hyphen?

Comment: Yes sr! 
that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

```
function tranformer(st) {
    let newStr = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
        if (i === 2 || i === st.length - 1) {
            newStr += "-"
        }
        newStr += st[i]
    }
    return newStr
}
```

Using Slice

```
let first = st.slice(0, 2)
let middle = st.slice(2, -1)
let last = st.slice(-1)
newStr = first + "-" + middle + "-" + last
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: this is not generic to any string

Comment: Its works on all type of input string. It add hyphen after second char and before last.

Comment: if he wants after second and before last thats perfect. what i mean is the way i saw the problem was that he wants a dash after the sequence of same char ends, the next char differs from the current one

Answer (score 0):

First I would decompose the string into an array, and then use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) command to insert a `-` char at the specified position:

```
let str = "xxzzzzzzzzx";

str = str.split('');

str.splice(2, 0, '-');  // insert - at pos 2
str.splice(str.length - 1, 0, '-');  // insert - at pos -1

console.log(str.join(''))  //-> xx-zzzzzzzz-x
```